# .htaccess — Variable location of affected folder

Tags: .htaccess

I have a PHP script to generate placeholder images, much like the [Placehold.it](http://placehold.it) service. I wanted a custom one to prevent the latency that often occurs with free online services.

I have included this script inside of the folder **./assets/placeholder/** in my personal front-end boilerplate. That is why I need a .htaccess that adapts to the current location of the placeholder folder, as it will not always be the root.

The script takes the following parameters: **d** (dimension, eg. 400, 250x100), **bg** (background color), **color** (text color) and **text**.

Ideally, the url would work as following `./assets/placeholder/300x200/EAEAEA/333333?text=Test`, with text being a regular GET var.

Here is the .htaccess that I put together a while ago. It works provided the file is in the root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^#([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?d=$1&bg=$2&color=$3 [QSA]
```

In one sentence, if I move this file (index.php) from the root to /some/other/dir/index.php, I want the .htaccess file to still function without have to change the RewriteBase or anything.

I have already found [this article on the matter](http://www.zeilenwechsel.de/it/articles/8/Using-mod_rewrite-in-.htaccess-files-without-knowing-the-RewriteBase.html), but I don't have enough knowledge on this subject to make it fit this case.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:** I decided to move the .htaccess file to the root of my project. The only thing not working is the adding of the / at the end, but before the ?

```
## Turn mod_rewrite engine on ##
RewriteEngine On

# No trailing / ?
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
# Add the slash. 
RewriteRule assets/placeholder/(.*)$ assets/placeholder/$1/ [L,R=301]

# Map parameters to get vars
RewriteRule assets/placeholder/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/$ assets/placeholder/index.php?d=$1&bg=$2&color=$3 [QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this url `.assets/placeholder/300x200/EAEAEA/333333&text=Test` to `.assets/placeholder/300x200/EAEAEA/333333?text=Test` if you want the QSA flag runs.

And try this code :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^assets/placeholder/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ index.php?d=$1&bg=$2&color=$3 [QSA]
```

Try also this code for the redirection the url with end slash :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^([^/]*)/$
RewriteRule assets/placeholder/(.*)$ assets/placeholder/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Is the index.php file in the root folder ?

Comment: Updated my original post to contain the working .htaccess code. Only thing missing is adding a / at the end, but before the ?. I copied some code from elsewhere but I wasn't able to adapt it to my situation.

Comment: Removed some comments here.. No success with the proposed changes though. I still have to add the /, and when not using one with the dimension (first) var, the url gets appended with `Applications/MAMP/htdocs/`, eg `http://localhost/Responsive-Boilerplate-0.1/assets/placeholder/300` becomes `http://localhost/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Responsive-Boilerplate-0.1/assets/placeholder/300/`